# Replacement DC Motor Not Working

Tags: dc-motor

I've been trying to fix this life-size dancing Christmas figurine by replacing its DC motor, however, I've been having some troubles. I checked the voltage rating from the wires and it's ~3.4v so I'm using a 3-12V 280 DC motor. I've bought several said DC motors from various sellers and none seem to move, oddly enough the original motor moves. Another thing that I seemed to have noticed is that whenever I connect my multimeter only to the wires, I get a voltage rating of ~3.4v, however, when I connect a DC motor in parallel: the rating drops to around 0.006v or so. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I've been trying all sorts of methods including using a step-up converter, different DC motor ratings, etc. however, nothing seems to change. It's worth noting that when I first tested the decoration, the board started smoking, however, after removing the old motor, the smoking ultimately went away. Not sure if this is board issue but would love to know why this happening. Many thanks! : )

Comment: `rating drops to around 0.006v` ... the power supply is not able to provide the required current to the motor

Comment: @jsotola It takes 9V 2A and I'm using the adapter that it came with originally. Everything else works, it's just the motor which either way should be enough to power it.